# Is Munkres defining determinant for $n\times k$ matrices ? If so, why this examples results in a square matrix?

Tags: determinant, differential-forms

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres at page 235, it is given that

[image]

However, shouldn't the rows of the matrix have 4 row since the vectors are from $\mathbb{R}^4$ ?

As my main question (where I think the problem is), in the same book and in the same page, it is given also that

[image]

However, if I'm not mistaken, the author defined a determinant function for $n\times k$ matrices, which is something that I thought is not defined until now, so just to be clear, is there anything wrong with this definition and with my understanding, or am I not getting what I'm reading (again) ?

Comment: The matrix $X$ is $n \times k$, but the matrix $X_I$ has only $k$ rows and is $k \times k$. The subscript $I$ means that we keep only the rows corresponding to the indexes in $I$.

Comment: @littleO Well, that is disappointing. I mean doing that leaves out some information about the matrix - i.e the rows from $k+1$ to $n$ - which is not nice. Anyway, thanks for the comment.

Comment: It's true that a particular $\Psi_I$ only cares about the rows of $X$ corresponding to the indexes in $I$. But, the collection of all $\Psi_I$ forms a basis of $\mathcal A^k(\mathbb R^4)$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas  I wouldn't think of it as disappointing, necessarily.  The standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ similarly consists of the vectors that care about only one position and ignore all others.

Comment: @Randall Yes, but in the above definition, for the basis element whose index is between $k+1$ - $n$, we get a zero matrix, so I do not see your point.

Comment: Why do you mention the rows from $k+1$ to $n$? $\Psi_I$ cares about the rows $i_1,\ldots,i_k$, not the rows from $1$ to $k$.

Comment: @littleO Yes, you are correct (I wrote that line while I was in a line); I just confused it, but nevertheless, that are $n-k$ rows that are ignores, isn't it ? or am I mistaken again ?

Comment: Yes, there are $n - k$ rows that are ignored by $\Psi_I$, that is correct.